# Custom Deserialization using Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to implement a university project where I try to fetch values from two Json fields and map it to one pojo class.

Sample Json:

```
"event":[{"D17-32":0,"S10":"D"}]
```

Pojo class

```
    public class Event {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SignalCustomDeserializer.class)
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
    @JsonProperty("S10")
    private Signal S10;

    @JsonProperty("D17-32")
    private String D17_32;
    //Getter and setter implementation
    }
```

Class which I need to serialize the fields to

```
    public class Signal{

       private String value;
       private String detectorId; 
       private int detectorValue; //this value has to be fetched from another json
      //Getter and setter implementation
    }
```

Custom deserializer class

```
    public class SignalCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

       @Override
        public Signal deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
          String signalId = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
          String signalVal = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
          String detectorVal = jsonParser.getValueAsString("D01-16");
          Signal signal = new Signal();
          signal.setValue(signalVal);
          signal.setDetectorId(getDetectorId(signalId));
          return signal;
       }
    }
```

I am able to get the signalId and signalValue but I am unable to get the value for the other field. I am unsure if its available in the JsonObject when the custom deserialization class is called.

Comment: can u post sample json value

Comment: What is your question? How does the JSON look like?

Comment: and where is signal.setDetectorValue(..) statement? is that your problem?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Added a sample json. My problem is I have a custom deserialiser defined for one field and I am trying to retreive value from another field. If you take a look at the signal field, it serializes to signal class where I am also trying to access the D01-16 field

Comment: @premkumar Added a sample json. My problem is I have a custom deserialiser defined for one field and I am trying to retreive value from another field. If you take a look at the signal field, it serializes to signal class where I am also trying to access the D01-16 field. It is coming as blank in the string so setting it won't help.

Comment: is your sample relevant to the given code ? i mean are the attributes appropriate?

Comment: @premkumar Yes, I took out some of the signal values from the big event string. I have changed it to S10 so that it becomes easier for you to understand.